# Please explain: Getting different $_SERVER['remote_addr'] results using jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating my first jquery mobile site and I'm getting conflicting results using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. I know getting/using ip addresses are unreliable, I'm concerned about why the following behavior happens.

Just an example:  On the log in page, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is saved into session variable $_SESSION['ip1'] as the page is being served. When the user submits the log in form, the form makes an ajax call to login.php on server.  The login.php script finds $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] does not contain the same value as $_SESSION['ip1'].

Other info: The 2 addresses are very different from one another and stay the same during each testing period. Also this behavior only occurs while using mobile broadband and not wifi. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile broadband provide might be using a Proxy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: +1. I have seen that the IP for HTTP would be different than the one for HTTPS (probably because only HTTP used a proxy). Maybe this is something similar.